# The way `Drop column by id ` result in all same columns removed in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd 
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[14, 4, 5, 4],"B":[1,2,3,4]}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[14, 4, 5, 4],"C":[5,6,7,8]})
df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```

Let's see the concated df,the first column and third column shares the same column name `A`.

```
df
    A  B   A  C
0  14  1  14  5
1   4  2   4  6
2   5  3   5  7
3   4  4   4  8
```

I want to get the following format.

```
df
    A  B  C
0  14  1  5
1   4  2  6
2   5  3  7
3   4  4  8
```

Drop column by id.

```
result = df.drop(df.columns[2],axis=1)
result
   B  C
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  7
3  4  8
```

I can get what i expect this way:

```
import pandas as pd 
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[14, 4, 5, 4],"B":[1,2,3,4]}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[14, 4, 5, 4],"C":[5,6,7,8]})
df2 = df2.drop(df2.columns[0],axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```

It is so strange that both the first and third column removed when to drop specified column by id.
1.Please tell me the reason of dataframe's this action.
2.How can i remove the third column at the same time keep the first column undeleted?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using indexes:

```
index_to_drop = 2

# get indexes to keep
col_idxs = [en for en, _ in enumerate(df.columns) if en != index_to_drop]

# subset the df
df = df.iloc[:,col_idxs]

    A  B  C
0  14  1  5
1   4  2  6
2   5  3  7
3   4  4  8
```

Comment: Please tell me the reason of dataframe's this action.

Comment: basically, `col_idxs` takes the columns by indexes which is then passed to `.iloc` accessor to select those columns.

Comment: Not why col_idxs =[0, 1, 3] ,but why my way result in all column named `A` removed.

Comment: because when you do `df.columns[2]` it select `A` i.e. name of the column and it removes all column `A` no matter how many times it is present in the data frame.

Comment: hence, you need to remove column by integer index values and not their labels.

Comment: I feel it a bug , illogical.

Comment: it's rare to see data frames with different column having same column name. pandas doesn't know when you say drop `A` which one of `A`s to drop, hence it drops all.